# How to connect and write SQL in Excel to upload data in MS Access?

Tags: sql, excel, database, ms-access

I have 3 tables in a MS Access database:

- Payment ( p_id, p_date, from_month, to_month, year, payment_no)
- Period ( pd_id, p_id, month, year )
- Details (d_id, p_id, emp_id, serial, amount)

`p_id` is a foreign key for both `Period` and `Details` tables.Besides, Payment Date and Payment no combination is unique here

Source is Excel data, in this format:

[image]

For this one row insert, will create one record in `Payment` and `Details` tables, and 3 records in the `Period` table, one record for each month value.

How can I link from my Excel to MS Access and create SQL insert command to upload this data into MS Access?

Comment: Assume you want these records associated by PK/FK. Are you using autonumber for PK? Why is Excel involved? Excel connecting to Access is a common topic as is vice versa. Make connection and run INSERT actions. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Yes, those are autonumber. I have to upload bulk amount data from excel with these format

Comment: Autonumber PK actually complicates. Have to first commit parent record, grab the newly created PK to include as FK in dependent records.

Comment: Sorry! Payment Date and Payment no combination is unique here. forgot to include

Comment: Would probably be easier to code from Access side. Have Access set a link to worksheet. Open recordsets, loop through records. Doesn't matter that PaymentDate and PaymentNo are unique combination, still need to grab the autonumber PK to save as FK. Your question is too broad and does not have code for analysis.